# hover on class not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="div box_position" id="something" style="some style" onlick="somefunction"</div>
</div>
```

These tags are created dinamically via jquery.

Now I have the following CSS:

```
.box :hover {
   background-color:red;
}

.div box_position :hover{
   border-color:black;
   font-size:20px
}
```

When I hover on the parent it works, but when I hover the content (the div box position) it doesn't change the color of the border or the font, Im I missing something?

Comment: Fix your divs! Fix your css! prior to asking the question! you are making everyone's answers make no sense since you keep changing the html and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There's a few things...**

- 1 Your `border-color` is defined incorrectly with the `=` sign.

You need to define it like so:

```
border-color: black;
```

- 2 Your second style definition is missing a `.` for the `box_position` class. Plus, I would change it to `box-position` to keep with most naming conventions.

You need to define your style like so:

```
.div .box-position:hover {
    border-color: black;
}
```

- 3 IMHO You don't really need to define a class called `div`, so you could remove this from the style definition. You could just declare your selector as "something inside a div", "called `box-position`.

Like so:

```
div .box-position:hover {
    border-color: black;
}
```

This says "anything that's in a div; and has the class of `box-position` - apply the following style to".

- 4 Your inner `div` is missing a closing angle bracket (`>`)

Should be this:

```
<div class="div box_position" id="something" style="some style" onlick="somefunction">
Some content
</div>
```

---

Also, ensure that you are defining a width for your border, unless this is declared elsewhere.

You can define the border's style short-hand, in one line only. Like so:

```
div .box-position:hover {
    border: 1px solid black; // Give me a 1px border that has a black, solid line
}
```

Lastly. I would consider your selectors, and have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp to familiarise yourself with what selectors mean/do and how to use this.

This will come in great help when you're defining your styles in future.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The correct answer, thank you, Point 3 was the key, the other things I copy pasted the html like an idiot,

Answer (score 1):

yes, you have a typo
`border-color=black;`

put `:` instead of `=`

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, but the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

should be  .box_position and use : (not = )
Assumining you don't have border

```
.div .box_position :hover{
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
   border-width: 1px;
 }
```

and also remove improper inline style .. (if inline fails the styling don't work) a proper onclick function call

```
 <div class="box">
    <div class="div box_position" id="something" onlick="somefunction()"</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Inner div is not closed properly (missing `>`).
2. Bug in CSS: should be `.div.box_position` instead of `.div box_position`.

Live code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOkbNY

**EDIT:**

Also, you have to specify the width and type of the border (done in the attached codepen).

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to put space between

```
.box :hover (incorrect)
.box:hover (correct)
```